# Is it possible to develop custom login page in angular8 to authenticate through Azure Ad API

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, angular8, azure-ad-msal

I've already applied the suggested azure ad authentication to my angular application where the azure ad either redirect to it's own login page or shows a popup , although my client is asking if i can create a custom login page and use azure ad api to authenticate the user. I was unable to find any example or such flow in azure ad documentation. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can not host login page. But you can customize your Azure AD sign-in page with some of the experience, with some text, images and logos.

reference:

[Add company branding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding)